# Partitioning of a set family that avoids small intersections

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, extremal-graph-theory, extremal-set-theory

Let $\mathcal{F}$ be the family of all $k$-element subsets of $[n]$. What is the smallest $\ell$ such that we can partition $\mathcal{F}$ into $\ell$ families $F_1,\dots,F_\ell$ with the property that none of the $F_i$ contains two sets that intersect in **at most two** elements?

Of course, one can generalize this question to intersections of size at most $r$, but I couldn't even figure out this "simple" case.
If no such lower bound is known, are there related problems I could look into?

**Update:** As pointed out in the comments, this is related to the the chromatic number of the generalized Kneser graph.

**Update 2:** Does finding such a lower bound become any easier if we assume $\mathcal{F}$ contains *all* subsets of $[n]$? (Of course, this assumption implies a trivial lower bound of ${n \choose 2} + n$ but is there anything better?)

Comment: In other words, you want the chromatic number of the [generalized Kneser graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kneser_graph#Related_graphs) $K(n,k,2)$.

Comment: Yes, or any lower bound on it.

Comment: for the family of all subsets, all sets with at most three elements must be of different color, right?

Comment: Yes, thus an easy lower bound would be $\sum_{i=1}^3{n \choose i}$.